# variable in string of dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have the following dictionary in python 3:

```
a = {'a': 'b:{androidString}'}
```

Try to define a variable and use it in the dictionary:

```
android = "androidString"

a = {'a': f'b:{{android}}'}
```

when:

```
print(a)
```

it says:

```
{'a': 'b:{android}'}
```

how to use the variable in the dictionary?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `f'b:{andriod}'`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
it is {'a': 'b:androidString'} not {'a': 'b:{androidString}'}

Comment: *What is the output you need*? It isn't clear

Comment: Whether you are dealing with nested json kind of format if yes the format is correct. Please clarify what is the needed output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a curly bracket :

```
a = {'a': f'b:{{{android}}}'}
```

Output

```
{'a': 'b:{androidString}'}
```

Comment: Thanks!
can you explain a little bit why need have another bracket?

Answer (score 0):

Just use get method:

```
...
a.get('a')
```

get method takes two parameters first key name , second default 
default returns Errors in default but you can change it to False 
so when you try to get key doesn't exists it will return default 

or you can use []:

```
...
a['a']
```

there are a lot options to get key of dictionary [More info](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)